# An Unconfirmed transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool.space

I made a transaction with a very low fee and it has been more than 14 days (2weeks) it’s still showing pending. No confirmation nothing. I’m just wondering what will happen. Will the transaction remain in the mempool forever? Or how can I solve this